# clear fluid leaking from 2001 Rav 4

Tags: rav4

I have a 2001 Rav 4, and I noticed this clear fluid leaking from a hose.
[image]

Does this have something to do with the air conditioning or is it the transmission fluid? This is a manual Rav 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fluid is water. It is condensate from the air conditioner evaporator.  It is normal. The black hose is the evaporator drain hose.